# Unable to create valid KQL query for Azure Custom log search as Metric alert type

Tags: kql, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

This is my KQL query

```
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(60m)
| where (ObjectName == "Processor")
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue) by Computer , _ResourceId
| where AggregatedValue < 100
| project Computer, AggregatedValue
```

**Error** : Search Query should contain 'AggregatedValue' and 'bin(TimeGenerated, [roundTo])' for Metric alert type

**Note** : Above query is working successfully (prints result) in  Azure Monitor - Logs as below image1.
But same query is throwing Error while running in as below image2.

[image: image1]

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
[image]

Comment: The error message seems very descriptive. Have you tried adding `bin(TimeGenerated, [roundTo])` (where *roundTo* is a timespan, E.g., 30s, 5m, 1h etc.) to the *by* clause?

Comment: Tried with this below query : same Error

'''
 Perf
| where bin(TimeGenerated, 1h) > ago(60m)
| where (ObjectName == "Processor")
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue) by Computer, _ResourceId
| where AggregatedValue < 100
| project Computer, AggregatedValue
'''

Comment: **"to the *by* clause"**

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz , I can't understand your comment, I'm new to KQL.Can you please help me constructing this query.

Comment: Try to put the bin expression as part of the summarize operator,  after the word *by*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems very descriptive. Tried adding *bin(TimeGenerated, [roundTo])*

It worked

```
    Perf
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
    | where CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName == "_Total" 
    | project TimeGenerated, Computer, CounterValue, _ResourceId
    | summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue)  by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Computer, _ResourceId
```

Thanks @David דודו Markovitz